# How do I accept global path parameter in Nest.js application?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am building a rest API for fully multi tenant system with single database and app. I am using NestJS and I want to base all of my modules on :tenantID I provide in the root location of my app.

So for example if I have modules users and conversations I want the endpoints to look like this:

`app_url/:tenantID/users`
`app_url/:tenantID/conversations`

I I couldn't find anything on how to do this

Comment: have you tried the [router module feature](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module)?

Comment: Yes, I could add :tenantID, but no way to handle that route and add logic based on param value

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the global parameter to every controller's route, like so:

app.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller(':account')
export class AppController {
    constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

    @Get()
    getHello(@Param('account') account: string): string {
        console.log(account)
        return this.appService.getHello();
    }
}
```

users.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller(':account/users')
export class UsersController {
    @Get()
    getUsers(@Param('account') account: string) {
        console.log(`Account ${account} has the following users:`);
        return true;
    }
}
```